# How do I add a user model to my application so data is "user" specific in my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic-oauth

looking to see if there are some ideas on how I should introduce the idea of a logged-in "user" that effectively 'federates' the data....let me explain.

I have been building my app so far as if there is only one user.  Me.  All the data and reports are specific to me.  I just added authlogic.

I now want to be able to introduce a way for a new user to log in, not see any of my data, and use the application.  And eventually to pay to use the system.

So far, my assumption is I'd have to go into the models and add a user_id to pretty much each of them, and then go to all controllers and have them search by user.

But I am wondering if there are gems, suggestions, ideas of a better way to federate the data for each user.

Oh...I may want to enable more than one user to have access to some or all of the data belonging to another user.  This is for small teams of sales people that may want to share.

So...ideas before I try fumbling around myself...thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea. You have to make relationships between users and the data models. In some cases, it might be a simple `belongs_to :user`, but if you want multiple users to access certain data, it's going to have to be a many-to-many relationship `has_and_belongs_to_many :users`.

Then, we simply change the way we fetch data:

```
# Some controller, no restrictions
def index
  @reports = Report.all
end

def view
  @report = Report.find(params[:id])
end

# Some controller, with restrictuons
def index
  @reports = current_user.reports.all
end

def view
  @report = current_user.reports.find(params[:id])
end
```

Using the above logic, users will only see whatever data they have a relationship to.

It's probably going to be a little bit of work if you've already created most of the application, no doubt. What you have to be really, really, *really* careful with is not leaving any `Report.all` or `Report.find(params[:id])` lying around, as that can lead to vulnerabilities--users would be able to access data that isn't actually theirs.

Comment: sigh -- thanks for the code-specifics, that's what Iw as looking for...hoping to find a silver bullet, but that's cool....

Comment: So does User have to has_many for *all* objects or should I try to find a way to find a single top-level object?  Seems more work to do every object, but probably more secure?

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is called ACL (access control lists). There are a number of plugins for Rails that will do the bulk of the work for you. Google around and see if you can find one that fits your needs.

Edit: After taking a quick look, [Acl9](http://github.com/be9/acl9) seems to be the most popular Rails 3 compatible one.

Comment: Not... really. ACL has more to do with restricting access to certain parts of the system, or controllers/actions in Rails-speak. Think "user 1 is an admin and can view, edit and delete other users," while "user 2 can list other users but not edit them" and "user 3 can't even see the users list." Angela, on the other hand, want all users to be able to access the same controllers and actions, but view different data.

Comment: that's right -- want same controllers and actions, but different data.

Comment: Ah, okay. I know what ACL is, I just misinterpreted what she was asking.